# tfsbuild cleanup jobs executing on inappropriate build agents

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a question about forcing/permitting where the TFS Build Cleanup jobs get run.  This is not a question of when they are run, but a question of how to direct TFS to run them on specific build server(s).  First the background:

I manage a small farm of on-premise build/release servers, all connected to an on-premise TFS2017 Update 2 system, with agent 2.117.2 installed on the build/release servers.  One of these build/release servers exists in a separate domain (our production domain) from our development domain, and purposely only has read access into the development domain.

Our builds, and development releases occur on the servers in the development domain, and those builds are directed to those build/release servers via build/release demands in the configurations. This all works well.

Its only been recently that we've had a release server in our production domain, and with that has come the realization that TFS is 'randomly' choosing  an available server on which build cleanup jobs are to be run.  This random allocation to an available build/release server is a problem.

While the cleanup jobs could run on any build/release server in the development domain without problem - they can not run on the release server in production as that server only has read access into the development domain by design. As a result, all triggered cleanup jobs on the production release server fail.

Is there a way to limit which execution agents the TFS Build Cleanup jobs are able to be triggered on?  Providing R/W access to the prod release server is not a desirable workaround to this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "build cleanup jobs"?

Comment: There are batch processes which are being triggered that (from what we can see) are deleting build artifacts

Comment: How is the batch process triggered? Is it in the build/release process? then why don't you set demands in the configurations?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT these are not the build/release jobs from what we can see as those do have demands which prevent them from being run on a queue which has insufficient access.  When we look at the jobs in question, these seem to be the TFS jobs that execute by the system to clean up (based on a schedule) after the builds... to delete build artifacts which no longer meet retention rules.